# Making a list from a document library

Tags: list, document-library, document, view, mapped-folder

I've got a document library named **Project**, with "Projectname", "Projectleader", "Building code", "Building" and "accountNr" fields. So my folders inside this library are called **projectname**.

In another part of the site, I want to publish a view for each building, with **project** and **projectleader** fields.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I recommend:

- Navigate to your **Project** document library
- Make sure each of your **projectname** folders have Project and **projectleader** fields populated. Even SharePoint folders can have custom fields associated with them.
- Create a new view in the **Project** document library.
- In the new view, select only columns you need. For example, **Project** and **project leader**
- The view should only return Folder content type
- Save the view and verify it only shows folders. There should be one folder for each project and two columns that you wanted to display.

**Now navigate to a SharePoint page**

- Add a document library webpart.
- Select a view that you created above.

Comment: I've 3 different SP pages A, B,C. 1 document library named Project. I can make the view for page A. But when I open page B, I see the view from A. I make a view for page B, but going to page A again,,, the view is B. How can I make a standard view per page A, B and C. So if I open the page A, I see the view A always and when I open page B, I see the view B.

Comment: I thought that document library webpart let's you pick views. It didn't work?

Comment: It did work thanks.

Comment: @Arthur, can you, please accept the answer if it helped you?